# Optimization of double for with .map / .filter / .reduce or something

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Is there a way to optimize the following with ES5 / ES6?

```
var obj = [];
var set;
for (var key_s in data1) {
    set = false;
    for (var key_s2 in data2) {
        if (data1[key_s].id === data2[key_s2].id) {
            obj.push({'id': data1[key_s].id,
                      'key': data1[key_s].key,
                      'value': data2[key_s2].value})
            set = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!set)
        obj.push({'id': data1[key_s].id,
                  'key': data1[key_s].key,
                  'value': "EMPTY"})
}
```

I want to have an object which contains all keys of `data1` and if a pair got the same `id` like the one in `data2`, it should take its `value`, otherwise it should become `'EMPTY'`. Or maybe is there a way to use `Object.assign` with some special parameters or something?

Comment: Optimize in what sense? Efficiency? Readability?

Comment: please add `data1` and `data2` as well and the wanted result.

Comment: Are `data1` and `data2` both arrays?

Comment: Start by [not using `for…in` enumerations on arrays!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for `data2` and use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with `data1` and the possible value of `data2`.

```
var map = new Map(data2.map(o => ([o.id, o]))),
    obj = data1.map(({ id, key }) => ({ id, key, value: map.has(id)
        ? map.get(id).value
        : 'EMPTY'
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). By specifying the `value` in the first parameter of `Object.assign`, you can set a default to be overridden by the object from `data2`.

```
var obj = data1.map(obj1 => {
  const obj2 = data2.find(obj2 => obj1.id === obj2.id);
  return Object.assign({ value: 'EMPTY' }, obj1, obj2);
});
```

Using [spread properties](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread), that `Object.assign` could be changed to:

```
{ value: 'EMPTY', ...obj1, ...obj2 }
```

Comment: you may add some other (unwanted) properties from `data2`'s objects ...

Comment: @NinaScholz That's true. I just made the assumption that there wouldn't be other properties, or that it wouldn't matter. I prefer your solution since it doesn't iterate `data2` each time.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty es6'ed. `map` over data1, the `.find` will return the matching object if one exists or else return `undefined`. set `key_s.value` to either the `key_s2` value or `"EMPTY"` and then return the key_s object. You will end up with an array of objects. This assumes that data1 and data2 are arrays of objects, that is how your example was written so I figured it was the case.

```
let obj = data1.map(key_s => {
  let newValue = data2.find(key_s2 => key_s.id === key_s2.id)
  key_s.value = newValue ? newValue.value : "EMPTY"
  return key_s
 })
})
```